# How to use Powershell to see status of an update in server?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, wsus

I made an update server using WSUS 6.3 on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter. I want to see the status of an update (e.g: KB3035583) using powershell. I know there are some way to do that but I don't know any of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following commands:

```
$wsus = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::getUpdateServer()
$wsus.SearchUpdates("KB3035583")
```

See the output for details of the update. Please note that KB number is not a unique specifier of an update, i.e multiple updates could have same KB number. So you may see multiple result from `.SearchUpdates` method.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I understand your question you need **Get-WsusUpdate** cmdlet.

Full information on the cmdlet:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826154(v=wps.630).aspx

List of WSUS PowerShell cmdlets:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826154(v=wps.630).aspx

A nice blog about how to use the UpdateServices PowerShell Module to Manage WSUS:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/05/27/use-the-updateservices-module-to-manage-wsus/

I hope it helps.

Comment: `Get-WsusUpdate` returns a list of all updates. For large amount of approved  updates, it causes time out error without any result!